# Source code for a Qiskit algorithm: HHL Algorithm

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-algorithms, hhl-algorithm

Is it possible to view the source code of one of the Qiskit's algorithm?
Actually, I am trying to find how Qiskit implements the HHL algorithm. I want to see the source code for this algorithm.

Comment: Do not forget to click on the "Accept" button if one of the answer answered your question.

Answer (score 6):

Qiskit is an open source. Specifically for HHL, see https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/master/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/linear_solvers/hhl.py.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Qiskit documentation. There is a source code for any of implemented functions and algorithms. In particular for HHL it is available here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/linear_solvers/hhl.html#HHL

When you get to a function/algorithm description it the [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/install.html), simply click on link Code and you will se the source code.